# Matplotlib , dimensione grafico impostata ... label "tagliati"

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

as from the topic .. sometimes happen that given a figure size for print a plot inside the label are partially cut .. as in the example reported [image]

there is some trick in order to fit the box and the label/title all inside the figure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
plt.savefig('fig.png',  bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: thank you !! works exactly as I needed !